# C# using a reference to an entity record?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I have three collections of records from a database which I use to generate a single list that I bind to a WPF list view.

Each list contains the same type of object: List

Each list refers to either the shortlisted records, the search results and a list of the related records to the selected one.

In the list view I group the records by one of the properties of the object.

To display the items I use the following method

```
/// <summary>
/// Updates the display by rebinding the data
/// </summary>
public void UpdateDisplay()
{
    //create the collection view source which performs the grouping
    var concatList = ShortlistImages.Union(GroupImages).Union(SearchImages).OrderBy(a => a.Type);       
    var lst = new CollectionViewSource { Source = new ObservableCollection<ItemImage>(concatList) };
    lst.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Type"));
    Items = lst.View;
    SelectedItem = concatList.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

The idea is that the user can double click one of the list view items and that will add it to the shortlist.

I have a method which is passed an ItemImage record that was clicked and does some stuff with it before adding it to the shortlist, but the main thing is it changes its type to SHORTLIST so that the list view will see it as being part of the shortlist group.

The record is then added to the shortlist collection.

**MY PROBLEM**

if I put a breakpoint on the first line of the method shown earlier then I can see that the item that I double clicked appears in both the shortlist and the search results collection which is good.

I also see however that both records have their type changed to shortlist. I only changed the type for the record that I added to the shortlist. I DID NOT change the type for the record in the original search results, this results in the item disappearing from the search results and appearing twice in the shortlist.

I imagine that this is due to C# using a reference to the record and not specific instances of the record.

**MY QUESTION**

How can I get C# to treat the records as distinct entities and not simply use a reference to the same record. or failing that is there something else I am not realising?

I have tried re-getting the record from the database just before I added it and that disnt work.
I have tried cloning the object and that didnt seem to work.

**I am using**

- C#
- WPF
- Entity Framework
- Visual Studio 2012
- A lot of coffee

Comment: While you copy the object to the shortlist,it use a reference and it applies changes on both list,so i guess the only way you have is to create a new object and copy the selected items properties to that before you add it to the shortlist.

Comment: Well it is a bit of a hack but it works so if you want to convert that to an answer then I will do some upvoting upon your answer and it shall be accepted